# AS3 game with levels as movieclips?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a game and each level is contained in a sprite. When I exit a level the sprite is removed from the stage and set to null. The problem is that all of the variables and event listeners inside the sprite are left untouched. Is there an easier solution than finding and disabling every game mechanic?

Answer (score 1):

I have a very similar approach. I don't know if it'll be useful to you, but here's more-or-less what I do. To be honest, your question is a little vague, but I'll take a crack at it.

(For any possible commentators, yes, I have code on my Timeline, and I know many consider that "bad practice". Trust me, the alternative isn't viable for my project. However, technically, one *could* do a similar thing to me using the document class, I suppose.):

--

I, too, have each "level" (actually, for me, each explore location) in a separate MovieClip. Each MovieClip, obviously, has its own code. However, variables and event listeners are initialized within a "startClip()" function. Then, cleanup tasks (such as removing event listeners and variables) are done in a "stopClip()" function.

These levels are placed on the stage by creating the MovieClip, and then calling startClip() on the MovieClip. When I want to switch to another level, I call stopClip(), and then remove the MovieClip.

One other advantage to this method is that I can have an additional MovieClip on the stage for the common GUI elements, so when I switch "levels", the common GUI is untouched.

I'm sure there are other methods of accomplishing the same thing, but this is what I do, and it works for me.

One more hint: you will cut down on what variables and event listeners you need to remove if you put most (if not all) of your common tasks on the Stage, in your document class, and if necessary, inside a custom class or two. I actually have a number of custom classes, and as a result, about 90% of the code within each MovieClip is just calling functions and variables within these classes.

For me, these custom classes control (among other things) scoring, sound playback, randomization tasks, common array tasks, and saving player progress.

Hope this helps!

Comment: A DocumentClass and OOP is the only clean approach. FrameScripts arent only a bad pratice it's a leftover from as2. Having said that, i always say"As long as it works, who cares". But since you have a semi OOP aproach(using some classes) i dont understand why not make it propper to begin with. And ive never seen a project where its not "viable" to do it the right way! Just saying ;)

Comment: Heh, there's always a first time. The problem is the sheer mass of my project. The game core alone exists close to 10,000 lines of code, with a few hundred thousand lines more in the timelines, and thousands of unique interactive elements. Also, there is the fact that 90% of my (incredibly complex) animated elements come from my non-programmer graphic designer, so it is impossible for me to create this stuff via code. Thus, I have to script on the Timeline. If I were to take the approach of putting everything in the document class, it'd be impossible to find one line of code out of millions.

Comment: BTW, watch out for phrases like "the only," "always," and "never." They're rarely true of any project. If they were, we'd have achieved modular "LEGO" programming by now.

Comment: Hehe ..  sry man, that must be one of the craziest things I’ve heard in 15years of game development. 10k of lines for a game core isn’t anything special, but 100k’s of lines scattered around the timeline is just pure frightening. Especially for a game. The poor coders entering the team at an advanced stage. I mean the whole point of OOP is to keep the project modular, easy maintainable, easy extensible and generally better manageable. I suggest to look at some sophisticated programming patterns like MVC, it would make everybody’s life involved in such big scale projects a whole lot easier.

Comment: The same is true for using SVN, which is impossible with framescripts. And I take it the source won’t be documented properly, since that doesn’t work either. Oh, and everybody gets their animations from non-coding designer. Nobody is saying anything against your stop(); commands at the start of animation’s, but that’s about it. Sry mate, I’m sure u’ve made a wicked game and ur a great guy and I defiantly don’t want to start an argument.

Comment: Since you obviously have some better answer to the poster's question, please enlighten us and share, because all I've gleaned from what you've posted so far is personal attacks, which don't help other readers.

Comment: na i dont. Having an init() and dispose() method for the Mc's is the right approach. And im sorry if you felt personally attackted, didnt mean to and thats not who i am!! I was just elaborating on your comment that framescripts are the better aproach for complex projects.
btw, i obviously dont mean to have all the source in one document class, but in multible classes each with their own purpose. Sorry again if u felt attacked. +1 for the right answer

Comment: I appreciate that. It may be a good idea to remove your earlier comments and summarize in a less personal way. What stands now would be of no use to the community, and may be considered a violation of community rules by an admin.